# TC fails on files with empty spaces in name on git project

Tags: git, teamcity, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

During TC build I occured with such problem:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project test-project: An error occurred during the status check process: Exception while executing SCM command. Error while executing command. Error inside systemOut parser: Illegal character in path at index 0: "java/releases/13.4.1/Prod/SomeFile%2013.1.1.docx" -> [Help 1]
```

So that means that something is changing files paths with blank spaces to character one, which is %20.
Whek we locally try to do the same in maven:

```
mvn -B release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseNumber=1.1.0 -DBUILD_VERSION=1.1.0.6 -Dsomeuser | tee ~/3.1.0.6.log
```

It performs well, on some random dev environment the same, on TC agent environment works fine as well. 
        Another point: I've tried scm:add such file and it forbids to do so., so I thouth that's it, but mvn prepare worked well and commited and pushed the data back.
    But teamcity build is failing again and again. We've checked out paths on agent after TC checkout and it didn't contain any %20 but space instead. So checkout it performs without such problem.
        I've tried some experiments with git and it performs such files well and we don't see any problems.

**What could it be and how to solve it?** Could it be problem with scm?
*P.S. We can't see at TC inner configurations, because doesn't have acces, just via web interface.*

Comment: if my suggestions below doesn't work for you, the quick fix may be to just remove the space in the file.  as a general rule, I'd say don't put spaces in files.  Use camelCase notation or underscores.

Comment: We've thought about changing names, but project is too big and there are over too many people, who commits in there, also there is some docs, oracle files, not just java, so this could occur again and TC would fail. We need another solution, if not, then change names and on pre-recieve hook forbid files with space in their names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out, that's this was scm problem when adding files. After renaming of all files it works fine. 
        Another approach is to add -DdryRun preventing to commit and push changes and invoke shell script with same commands but with common git commands.
        If anyone knows another approach - please write a comment.

Comment: What VCS are you using?  I've seen a similar problem in the past with SVN from Windows users.

Comment: Git. It was in the description. Git works fine with such files, it's maven git scm provider, which fails in such situations.

Answer (score 3):

What helped me was the following (from https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/):

> Remove every file from Git's index.
>
> `git rm --cached -r .`
>
> Rewrite the Git index to pick up all the new line endings.
>
> `git reset --hard`

hth

Comment: This fixed it for me, too. Seems like the maven release plugin has problems if a file contains CRLF line endings. Following these instructions eventually helped: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings
Funnily enough, the server, that jenkins was running on recognized a lot more changed files than the git setup on the development machine (still investigating the cause of that). So we eventually had to do the line ending normalization there.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to replace any % in teamcity with %% in order to logically use a % sign.  So %%20 may work for you.

Comment: How could I do this? Is there some configuration or via some step? Basically, Teamcity don't do such things, only via some plugins, triggers or adding/changing some parameters to some tools (like git) - that's how I understand it.